# How to pass references of declared variables to C function in python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I would like to call a C function from python. This C function is void, thus the "return parameters" (data I want to change) are defined as pointers in the C function's definition.

The function in C looks like this (note: I cannot and will not change it as it is generated automatically by [MATLAB codegen](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html)):

```c
void func(int   *input_var,    // input
          float *output_var    //output
         ) {
    ... 
}
```

from python, I am calling my function as so

```py
import ctypes as C

func = C.CDLL('path/to/lib.so').func

input_var = C.c_int(5)
output_var = C.POINTER(C.c_float) # basically want to just declare a pointer here
func(C.byref(input_var), C.byref(output_var))
```

The error I get is

```
TypeError: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not '_ctypes.PyCPointerType'
```

if I remove `bref()` I get

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

I also tried to pass in output_var as `C.byref(output_var())`; this leads to a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: `POINTER(c_float)` is a *type*. An instance would be `POINTER(c_float)()` but what you actually need is just a float instance: `float()`. Pass it `byref`

Comment: creating the instance works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

Do things like you'd do it from *C* (and you're already doing for the input argument): declare a *float* variable and pass its address to the function (via *byref*).

**One important thing**: check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall when working with *CTypes* (calling functions).

Example (simplest scenario: pointers wrapping single values, if there were arrays, or function performed some memory allocations, things would be a bit more complex).

- *dll00.c*:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL00_EXPORT_API void dll00Func00(int *pIn, float *pOut);

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif


  void dll00Func00(int *pIn, float *pOut)
  {
      if (pIn)
          printf("C - In: %d\n", *pIn);
      if (pOut) {
          float f = 3.141593 * (pIn ? *pIn : 1);
          printf("C - Setting out to: %.3f\n", f);
          *pOut = f;
      }
  }
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import sys


  DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


  def main(*argv):
      dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
      func = dll.dll00Func00
      func.argtypes = (cts.POINTER(cts.c_int), cts.POINTER(cts.c_float))
      func.restype = None

      i = cts.c_int(2)
      f = cts.c_float(0)

      res = func(cts.byref(i), cts.byref(f))
      print("Values after calling function: {:d}, {:.3f}".format(i.value, f.value))


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Output**:

> ```
> (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q075393602]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -shared -o dll00.so dll00.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> C - In: 2
> C - Setting out to: 6.283
> Values after calling function: 2, 6.283
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: This makes sense, however reading your specific scenario was a little confusing wrt my situation since you are initializing your output variable `f` with a value (`0`). But in my case it turns out that with ctypes you can "declare" a variable by instantiating one without an argument/value, i.e., `c_float()` as explained by @Mark Tolonen

Comment: :) It's like in *C*: you can have `float f;` or `float f = 0;`. I always initialize variables (it's a habit of mine not to rely on compiler defaults). Anyway in *CTypes* the 2 are equivalent, as if you print the "uninitialized" one it's still *0* (initialized by default). Also it's a good thing in your situation, as you can clearly see that the function actually changed the value.

Comment: I see; I was unaware of this compiler default behavior!

Comment: Actually I misread the comment. `POINTER(c_float)()` creates a *float\** (which is ***NULL***). Now, I don't know what the function does inside (whether it handles that case or not, or if it allocates memory, and so on). Passing a *NULL* pointer in **my function** doesn't do anything with it, therefore there's no return value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .byref directly after declaring the variable no need to make a pointer.

so in your example, you can declare the output as the variable type you need it to be and then pass that by reference to the function.

```
 output_var = C.c_float()
 func(C.byref(input_var), C.byref(output_var)
```

this should work.

Comment: No, it won’t work. `c_float` is a type. You need an instance: `c_float()`